# how does an android app read data from the database/server?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple android app.  All I want the app to do is connect to my server/database and run a query. whatever the returned string from the DB is should be displayed on the screen.

I have not found any examples of an app that show this. the [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) doesn't have anything like that.

How does this work?

- Does the android app connect to the actual database and run queries?
- Does the android app require a restful API on the server?

Comment: There are examples included with the SDK. See, for instance, Samples\Android-7\ContactManager (located under your Android SDK directory location). (There are also copies under the Android-8 and Android-9 folders.)

Answer (score 0):

Just use web service then only you can access the data from server database. I think this process is done by JASON technique. Just you refer how to pass your string to URL from your Android application. That's enough.